# How do I disable text areas based on what radio button is checked when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I want to improve upon this [script](https://jsfiddle.net/hkwq1yey/1/) for disabling text areas by radio button selection. Currently when "yes" is selected the text areas should be disabled and enabled when "no" is selected.

What do I need to change so the text areas are disabled  when the page first loads and if the correct radio button is checked?(yes is checked by default if no change has been made)

Please bare in mind this page will be refreshed and redirected to so I will need to check the actual selection on the radio buttons. I was just setting them to all be disabled on load before but this disabled text areas even when I had the correct radio button selected.

HTML

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="yes" checked/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="no" />No
</div>
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="yes" checked/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="no" />No
</div>
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice3" value="yes" checked/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice3" value="no" />No
</div>        
<div>
    <textarea data-trigger="choice1" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
    <textarea data-trigger="choice2" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
    <textarea data-trigger="choice3" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
```

Javascript/JQuery

```
    $(function () {

    var $choices = $(".group").find(":radio");
    $choices.on("change", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var choiceName = $this.attr('name'); 
        var tarea = $('[data-trigger="' + choiceName + '"]');
        if ($this.val() === "yes") {
            tarea.val('');
            tarea.prop('readonly', true);
            tarea.css('background-color', '#EBEBE4');
        } else {
            tarea.prop('readonly', false);
            tarea.css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        }
    });
});
```

Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: You could just trigger change event on document ready or set `readonly` (or `disabled`)  attribute by default in HTML markup. Just be aware, `readonly != disabled` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(".group").find(":radio[value=yes]:checked").each(function () {
    $('[data-trigger="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]').prop('readonly', true).css('background-color', '#EBEBE4');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q9wk7wbm/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add the class attribute to your textarea

```
<div>
    <textarea data-trigger="choice1" rows="4" cols="20" class="group"></textarea>
    <textarea data-trigger="choice2" rows="4" cols="20" class="group"></textarea>
    <textarea data-trigger="choice3" rows="4" cols="20" class="group"></textarea>
</div>
```

in your script:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("textarea.group").attr("disabled", true);
});
```